# Django Database change from SQLlite to PostgreSQL DateTime Field error Solving globally for all model fields

Tags: postgresql, django-2.1

How can I solve this error:

```
" django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type time without time zone to timestamp with time zone "
```

I got this while using the migrate command after changing my Django Database from sqllite to postgres. Is there a solution settings that I can add to solve it for all fields in my project with type `DateTimeField` and using `Timestamp`

```
time_created = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I kinda reset my Db it worked, by deleted db and doing migrate again ( i also deleted the migration files where i changed DateTimefield from TimeField ) u can also do it by altering it manually from postgresql as i didnt have much to lose here i just reset by database, hope it explains.